# How can i change UIButton TitleLabel Element

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Xcode natively set this property but impossible with mono touch! how can i set this properties

```
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeClip;
```

TitleLabel property is readonly property in mono touch. and override this property doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `TitleLabel` has only a getter is normal. It's the same in ObjC, e.g. from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel).

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UILabel *titleLabel
```

However that's not an issue in your code (either for Xamarin.iOS or ObjC) since you are **not** setting a new `UILabel`. What the code is doing is setting properties on the label.

IOW it's **readonly** because you cannot set a **new** `UILabel` instance to the `UIButton`, but it's fine to **modify** the existing instance. So the following C# code will work (just as your original ObjC does):

```
button.TitleLabel.NumberOfLines = 1;
button.TitleLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
button.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.Clip;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing won't work because you need to specify the state of the button. The button can have different titles for different states.

Call it like so:

```
 [button setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```

After that if you need to specify other properties you can do it like so:

```
-setTitleColor:forState
```

It is documented here: [apple reference for UIButton titleLabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel)

Comment: problem is not with xcode and objective c. that works perfectly but monotouch with c# doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
    [back.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [back.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [back.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
```

you can change button title element using button set method.